# CSS animation: Slide open a text container without given height

Tags: css, flexbox, css-animations

I try to slide a text open between two parallel lines, like a roll of parchment.
If I know the exact height of the text beforehand and put it in the keyframes at 100%, everything works fine.

However, the height of the text is variable. So on stackoverflow, for example, it is advised to set the max-height to a very high value. This also works.
However, cubic-bezier timing is then not possible.

Is there a solution for cubic-bezier without knowing the exact height?

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  max-width: 500px;
}

.wrapper .line {
  flex: 1;
  border-top: 2px solid #000;
  height: 2px;
  width: 100%;
}

.wrapper .text {
  overflow: hidden;
  animation-name: text-animation;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.23,.69,.09,.95);
}

@keyframes text-animation {
  0% {
    max-height: 0;
  }
  100% {
    max-height: 2000px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="line"></div>
  <div class="text">
    <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    </p>
    <p>
    Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
    </p> 
    </div>
  <div class="line"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: No, you won't be able to get precise timing with the max-height workaround - independent of what timing function you actually use. If the element was only 100px high, and you animated to a max-height of 1000px over ten seconds with basic linear timing - then all content would still have been revealed after only one second has passed, and the remaining nine seconds are simply "idle time" in which nothing actually happens any more. I don't think there is any pure CSS solution to this, you'd need to involve JS to actually measure the content height.

Comment: @CBroe Thanks, I have solved it with javascript for now. But let's see, maybe someone will come around the corner with a miracle.